# Differentiability of a function and continuity of its derivative.

Tags: calculus

If I make the following argument
Since rhd of $f$ is same as rhl of $f'$, similarly for left side, and we know rhd =lhd= $f'(a)$, as it is given that the function is differentiable, then have we not proven that $f'(x)$ is continuous at x=a?

Since rhl of f '(x) at x=a (=rhd of f(x)) = lhl of f '(x) at x=a (=lhd of f(x))= f'(a) (by definition of the derivative at x=a)

If you agree, then consider

$ f(x) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x})  & \mbox{if } x \neq 0 \\
  0 & \mbox{if } x=0
 \end{array}
\right.$

This function is differentiable at $0$, but its derivative is discontinuous.

If my premise is wrong, please prove so....thanks
I know that a proof by counter example is valid in maths, but I would appreciate an algebraic proof as to why my statement is wrong.

Comment: You consider only one-sided derivatives at a particular point. They are not limits of derivatives, but of difference quotients. You don't say anything about behavior of the derivative in other points. How could that prove continuity?

Comment: Firstly, I did not clearly get the first 3 lines.  I am in the last yr of high school, so if u restrict ur arguments to this domain, it will be easier for me to understand.

Comment: Moreover, I am talking abt continuity at THAT point. So why does the derivative need to be defined over an interval containing the same point? Maybe you could  take  another look at the function I talked about. Its derivative exists for all real nos. Then why isnt that derivative continuous at 0?

Comment: Upvote because it's a good question but it is one of the text-book classics, my fav analysis book has the graph on the front cover.

Comment: Alec, it is a typical eg of the invalid claim I made. I know the graph, but I dont see where my basic argument has gone wrong

Comment: what rhd/rhl means?

Comment: Left hand and right hand derivative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RHD of $f(x)$ at $x=a$ is $\lim_{x \to a^+} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$.

The RHL of $f'(x)$ at $x=a$ is $\lim_{x \to a^+} f'(x)$ = $\lim_{x \to a^+, h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$.

Your mistake is stating these are the same thing.

Comment: I do see that there is a problem in my assumption,  however, on a cartesian plane, for an arbitrary curve, the assumption makes perfect sense.

Comment: It only makes sense for precisely those 'curves' for which $f'(x)$ is continuous, which is what you are trying to prove. Clearly there are other graphs for which this does not apply, such as the one in your post.